# Test if key is in object in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component with an `errors: {}` object in the state.  This object essentially mirrors the `user: {}` object, which gets data from a form in the component.

The error object will store any error messages that are returned from attempting to save to the data store.

**For example**
If the person forgets to enter field `username`, the response will contain an "errors" object.  The actual error message will be in: `errors.username.message`

**The component to display** this error message should display if the message exists.  I pass the potential error message through a prop errorText:

```
<Input value={ user.username } name="username" errorText={ errors.username } 
    placeholder="username"
    displayName="Database Username" type="text" onChange={ updateFormField } />
```

This is working, whether errors.username is actually a key in the object or not.

However, I am getting an error in my Input component because it can't find `message` of `undefined`.

I thought I could test for the key using `in` but was incredibly wrong about this.  Here is my Input component:

```
export const Input = (props) => (
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor={ props.name }>{ props.displayName }</label>
            <input type={ props.type } value={ props.value } placeholder={ props.placeholder } 
                name={props.name} id={props.name} onChange={ props.onChange } className="form-control"/>

        { "errorText" in props ? "message" in props.errorText ? (
            <label className="label label-danger">{ props.errorText.message }</label>
        ) : "" : (
            ""
        )}
    </div>
);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `errorText={ errors.username }` prop to you `Input` component. This prop is set even if `errors.username` resolves to `undefined`. That means that your props in your `Input` component look like `{ errorText: undefined }`.

Now `"errorText" in props` resolves to `true`, since there actually is such a key, but `"message" in props.errorText` throws an error, because `props.errorText` is `undefined`.

You can change this to smth like:

```
props.errorText !== undefined 
  && props.errorText.message !== undefined 
  && <label className="label label-danger">{props.errorText.message}</label>
```

Comment: That was exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compare to `undefined`

```
{ props.errorText !== undefined ? props.errorText.message !== undefined ? (
    <label className="label label-danger">{ props.errorText.message }</label>
) : ( "" ) : ("")}
```